# How to get this XmlAttribute

Tags: c#, xml, rest, musicbrainz

From the MusicBrainz REST service, I get the following xml:

```
<artist-list offset="0" count="59">
  <artist type="Person" id="xxxxx" ext:score="100">
  ...
```

Using WCF and XmlSerializationFormat, I'm able to get the type and id attributes... but How do I get the "ext:score" one?

This works:

```
  public class Artist
  {
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public ArtistType Type { get; set; }
```

But this doesnt:

```
[XmlAttribute("ext:score")]
public string Score { get; set; }
```

It produces a serialization exception. I've also tried just using "score", but it doesn't work.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute is *named* "score", and is in the namespace referenced by "ext", which is presumably an xml namespace alias.

So find what "ext" maps to (look for an xmlns), and add:

```
[XmlAttribute("score", Namespace="http://example.org/ext-9.1#")]
public string Score { get; set; }
```

Edit; found it [here](http://wiki.musicbrainz.org/MusicBrainz_XML_Meta_Data); see `xmlns:ext="http://example.org/ext-9.1#"`. Also note that the main objects seem to be in `xmlns="http://musicbrainz.org/ns/mmd-1.0#"` which you may need to account for at the root/object level.

Answer (score 1):

The `ext` is the namespace of the `score` attribute. Try specifying the namespace:

```
[XmlAttribute(AttributeName="score", Namespace="the ext namespace")]
```